# Interacting with the shell in Java

Tags: java, shell, process, command-prompt, stdin

I was trying to write something that was eventually supposed to look like a bot for NetHack. However I ran into a few problems I have not been able to solve myself so far.

The first reason is that for some odd reason NetHack, and possibly other tty interface programs, doesn't run when simply ran from a `ProcessBuilder`. I have confirmed that it does however work for other programs (e.g. Notepad++).
I figure that this is because NetHack actually prefers to be run from a terminal and then to use that until it's done, but Java isn't a terminal so it freaks out and dies.

So I decided to try and to build a shell instead and from that run NetHack. However that introduced some other problems.

The first is that when I read the input stream (`stdout`) instead of returning `-1` or anything at all when there is nothing to read, `InputStreamReader.read()` simply blocks. This doesn't happen at a predictable position in the terminal, as it does only when the end of the text in the terminal is reached.

The second is that when I try to write something to `stdin` (not forgetting to `flush()`, nothing happens. (Tested by trying to `write("echo 1")` and `read()`ing the result)

I don't think that there is a solution to the first problem (not involving editing NetHack's source), and I am not sure how to deal with the other two.

(Note: I am actively trying to avoid relying on scripts or pre-existing frameworks)

Any help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: The last problem was solved by appending `System.lineSeperator()` (which was to be expected). Also, Java seems to absorb the terminal screen, why does it do that and is there a way to undo that, that would make debugging this a lot easier.